# Freebase 'alias' dataset dump

Tags: freebase

Does a dataset dump file for Freebase's aliases exist (e.g. for 'Sports' topic - sport teams' aliases, athletes' aliases and so on)?

I know I could get the aliases for a specific object via  http request/application but I just need a list of the aliases and do not want to issue http requests for 2.5 millions(or more) times..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All aliases are included in the quad & RDF dump files.
http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/Data_dumps